# Change px to em boostrap 3 SASS version

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-sass

Is there any possible way to change `bootstrap 3.1 SASS` version to `px to em` support for fonts

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do it manually, but it doesn't look like [there's any official release](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/373) that uses `em` instead of `px`. One of the creators, "mdo", left this comment in 2011:

> Browsers have switched to page zooming over scaling and there is no logical reason to use percentages or ems anymore. The overhead just isn't worth it with figuring out the math and managing that.